# JavaScript: Changing object value if another object has the same value in another property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects with the properties name, pref, and table. I need to check if one object has the same pref value as any other objects name value. I've written some code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```js
function seat() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].pref != "") {
      for (var c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
        if (data[i].pref == data[c].name) {
          data[i].table = data[c].table
          console.log(data[i].table + "first pref val");
          console.log(data[c].table + "second pref val");
        }
      }
    }

    function randomize() {
      let counts = [
        [1, 6],
        [2, 6],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 6]
      ];
      data.forEach(obj => {
        let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * counts.length);
        obj.table = 'table' + counts[i][0];
        if (--counts[i][1] == 0) counts.splice(i, 1);
      })
    }
    randomize(1, 4);
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Right here ^");
  };
};


var data = [{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
  {
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
  },
];


seat();
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please shorten it to show the issue with as little code as possible

Comment: @mplungjan Oh, ok sorry.

Comment: @jscoder001, if i would know what you **really want** (and the last three questions does not make it clear), i could help you. please add the purpose of the code and what you like to achieve.

Comment: All your `pref` are set to the empty string, and never receive another value...

Comment: @NinaScholz Ok, so I'm making a seating chart generator. You input the names of the people and who they would like to sit by in an HTML form. The JS then randomly generates a round number (1-4) and sorts them into tables. I have everything working except the part that moves preferences into the same table as who prefers them. I'm having trouble with figuring out how to go about this.

Comment: @trincot They are set by an HTML form

Comment: So you want to maximise something? The number of people who can sit at the same table as those they have marked as preferred? Do I see correctly that every table has 6 seats? Do I see correctly that there are 4 tables? Are they all the same?

Comment: @trincot 6 people are able to sit at one table, but that is regulated in the seat() function.

Comment: So what do you aim for? A perfect solution? What if person A wants to sit with B, and B with C, and C with D, ... etc... How would you solve that?

Comment: @trincot Well, in the situation where this would be used that would be unlikely. But, I just want to get basic functionality done before I move on to more complicated scenarios such as that.

Comment: What is "basic functionality"? Putting people at tables where they are not together with the preferred person? There are many scenarios where a perfect solution is not possible. Imagine 6 groups of 4 where they would like to be together with their group mates.... Is that unlikely?

Comment: No, but in this question I just want to be able to sort a perfect scenario. Then I will move on to addressing situations such as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign friends to the same group: if anyone's preferred person is in an existing group, they are added to that same group, etc. This way you can group all persons into distinct groups, where it is sure that there is no chain of preference from a person in one group to a person in another group.

Then you could sort those groups in order of descending size. Taking the largest groups first, you could assign them to the first table that still has room to seat that whole group.

If ever a group cannot be seated at any table, you should give up, as this means (in your configuration of 4 tables and 6 seats) there is no solution to seat everyone with their preferred person.

Here follows a function that does that. I have added code to make the snippet work with input, but the essence is in the first function:

```js
function seat(data) {
    // Key the persons by name and add some extra properties
    const hash = data.reduce( (acc, person, i) =>
        acc.set(person.name, Object.assign(person, {
            id: i,
            group: null
        })), new Map );
    const groups = [];
    const free = new Set(hash.values());
    while (free.size) {
        const group = new Set();
        let person = free.values().next().value; // first in Set
        // Add chain of preferrences to same group
        while (person && person.group === null) {
            free.delete(person);
            group.add(person);
            person.group = group;
            person = hash.get(person.pref);
        }
        if (person && person.group !== group) { // merge groups
            group.forEach( p => {
                p.group = person.group;
                p.group.add(p);
            });
        } else {
            groups.push(group); // add group
        }
    }
    const counts = [6, 6, 6, 6];
    groups.sort( (a, b) => b.size - a.size ) // descending size
        .forEach( group => {
            let table = counts.findIndex( count => count >= group.size );
            if (table === -1) {
                alert('No solution possible');
                return;
            }
            counts[table] -= group.size;
            // Assign table (table1, table2, table3 or table4)
            group.forEach( person => person.table = 'table' + (table + 1) );
        });
}

// Below follow the functions to make this demo work 
(function populate() {
    const persons = [...Array(6*4).keys()];
    // template row:
    const $row = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').append($('<input>')),
        $('<td>').append(
            $('<select>').addClass('pref')
                .append($('<option>'), persons.map(function (i) {
                    return $('<option>').val(i+1).text('person' + (i+1));
                }))
        ),
        $('<td>').append(
            $('<select>').addClass('table')
                .append($('<option>'), [1,2,3,4].map(function (i) {
                    return $('<option>').val('table' + i).text('table' + i);
                }))
        )
    );
    // Fill table with names
    $('table').append(
        persons.map( i => {
            $tr = $row.clone();
            $('input', $tr).val('person'+ (i+1));
            // Remove option to select the same person as preferred
            $('.pref>option', $tr).get(i+1).remove();
            return $tr;
        })
    );
})(); // execute immediately

function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}

// Allow to assign "random" choices for the preferred persons
$('#rand_pref').on('click', function () {
    const persons = [...Array(6*4).keys()];
    shuffle(persons);
    $('tr').each(function (i) {
        // Select kind-of-random preferred compagnion, 
        // but in a way that it is solvable
        const j = persons.indexOf(i);
        let k = ((j % 6)>>1 !== 1) ? j ^ 1 
                : j + Math.sign(Math.random() - 0.5);
        $('.pref', this).val(persons[k] + 1);
    });
});

// Allow names to be changed:
$('input').on('input', function() {
    $('.pref>option[value=' + ($(this).closest('tr').index()+1) + ']')
        .text($(this).val());
});

// On click: collect input, and generate solution
$('#assign').on('click', function() {
    // collect input
    var data = $('tr').map(function () {
        return {
            name: $('input', this).val(),
            pref: $('.pref>option:selected', this).text(),
            table: $('.table>option', this).val()
        };
    }).get();
    // Calculate seating
    seat(data);
    // Display result
    $('tr').each(function (i) {
        $('.table', this).val(data[i].table);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
<button id="rand_pref">Randomise preferred persons</button>
<button id="assign">Assign to tables</button>
```

Use the snippet's full-page mode to see the whole table.

Comment: you never give up!

Comment: @trincot Wow, I think you may have done it. Just to clarify is there JS I should leave out or are you referring to the HTML as the code you added. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The code outside of the first function is there to provide the interface with the HTML, allow data entry, and provide some help with random input. But the logic is in the first function. It should be possible to inject it in your code without much hassle. I just note that you had `data` as a global. It would be better to pass it to `seat` as argument. That way that function does not need to reference any globals.

Comment: @trincot Ok, I'm going to put this into my code and see how it all plays out. Based on what I saw when I ran the snippet, it should work with no problems! Thanks again.

Comment: @trincot Ok, one quick question. I think I'm missing something obvious here, but how can I pass it as an argument as you said? When I run the code how it is I get a TypeError on `data.reduce` saying data is undefined.

Comment: If `data` is undefined, it means you are either not passing anything as argument in the call to `seat`, or what you pass is literally `undefined`. It should be like in the code in your question: first you define somehow the value for `data`, and then you call `seat(data)`.